# javascript img.filter.item.aspply doesn't work in IE 10

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, filter

I have been using this JavaScript function for 5 years now, but something changed in IE 10 which is not allowing to execute.

```
var item = $get(params[1]);
var image = item.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];   
image.filters.item(0).Apply();
```

This has been working fine in IE 6-7-8-9, but with IE 10, it is unable to find `image.filters` property.

Please let me know if there is a way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, Microsoft removed support for DX filters from IE10. You can read about it here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/04/legacy-dx-filters-removed-from-ie10-release-preview.aspx

From Microsoft themselves:

> As we’ve written many times on this blog, users benefit when all
>   browsers support the same standards-based markup and all sites serve
>   standards-based content to all browsers.
>
> **We encourage all developers to serve the same standards markup to IE10
>   and move your sites off of IE’s legacy filter features today.**

As far as a workaround, that depends on the filter in question, but you can accomplish most things with CSS in IE10. Or look into something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to help you out.